# Sufficient statistics for Data Cleaning

Tags: statistics

If you want to do data cleaning (e.g. suppose you have 1000 data points), is finding sufficient statistics a good thing to do? Because this seems to reduce the extra noise of the data.

Comment: I m sure it s a good question for this forum too, but just wondering whether you may get an answer more quickly on the stats stack exchange ?

Comment: We need more information.  There's no such thing as a sufficient statistic until there's a family of probability distributions.